Fixed navigation on locomotive JS
I am new to locomotive and trying to achieve fixed navigation. here is the site http://dcwebportal.com/. The issue if keep the nav code inside the #main element links redirecting to the section but through css can not control the nav menu fixed position through css. Fixed position worked when I put the code outside the #main div but links of the menu are not redirecting to the particular section on the page.
Here is the website http://dcwebportal.com/
I would appreciate if someone help on this.
To have the fix navigation on the top and working menu link.
